# Troubles with admob mediators

Tags: android, admob

I'm having some troubles with monetization of my Android apps, The question is I can"t understand how to use the mediation service :(

I'm trying to make a video rewards thing, right, I saw this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TIiY1VIIQwg of admob garage, and it said that first step is set up mediated networks, then I had to watch this another video that should taught how https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sFew8Squ4pE, but the example use a fake network, and now I'm really lost.

I wanna to use 2 of this mediators, the Chartboost and Unity Ads, when I click to add any in admob, the Unity Ads for example, the admob show me this [image], So my first and silly question is I have to have a account in each network that I wanna to use in order to create this API Key? for example, in this case I had to have a Unity Ads account and a Chartboost account? And another thing, my app is not a game, so what I have to put in Game ID? Done all that and then? I mean how I'll receive? by admob or separatelly by each network account?

Please anyone can help me?

**Note** - I wanna continue to using the admob for now, I don't want to change for other, the Appodeal for example.

Answer (score 1):

I'm the guy in the videos you linked. Let me see if I can answer your questions.

> I have to have a account in each network that I wanna to use in order to create this API Key? for example, in this case I had to have a Unity Ads account and a Chartboost account?

Yes. In order to use AdMob mediation to show ads from Unity and Chartboost, you need to have an account with both Unity and Chartboost, just like you would if you were using their SDKs directly. Mediation uses the same Unity and Chartboost SDKs that people use normally, and they require you to have an account with those networks, with valid game IDs, placement IDs, and so on.

> And another thing, my app is not a game, so what I have to put in Game ID?

"Game ID" is a term Unity uses, since most of their apps are games. It identifies the app that's making the ad requests. I believe you can use Unity ads with non-game apps, but you'd need to check with them.

> Done all that and then? I mean how I'll receive? by admob or separatelly by each network account?

You'd get checks from each individual network. AdMob mediation manages how and when ads are requested from each network by your app, but it doesn't affect how money is transferred or collected. You'd still be paid by each network for the ads you showed from that network.

BTW, last week AdMob [launched its own rewarded video ads](https://admob.googleblog.com/2017/03/admob-is-leveling-up-your-business-with-new-app-monetization-innovations.html), which means you can now get rewarded video ads directly from AdMob, with no mediation required. So you're welcome to start with that, and add mediation later as you go.

Comment: Hey man, really thanks. And sorry about the silly question about have to have each network account, I'm new on this and work alone :) Can I ask one more question? You said that now I do nto need that mediation to show rewards videos, right, but I have that import some kind of adapter of admob? 'cause I've tried to create the videos without add any mediator but nothing happens, the project return always error code 0, and the example https://github.com/googleads/googleads-mobile-android-examples/tree/master/admob/RewardedVideoExample of developers site

Comment: (continuing) also don't show anything, on emulator it display no error, on the real device it's shown onRewardedVideoAdFailedToLoad, and teh error code 1