# Still having problems with reward videos on Admob - error code 3

Tags: android, admob

I'm still having some kind of weird problem with reward video on Admob. PLEASE, someone can help me?

This is my code, if anyone can find where is the error or what is missing, I'll thank you forever.

build.gradle

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:10.2.0'
```

AndroidManifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

<meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

<activity
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent" />
```

MainActivity

```
private RewardedVideoAd rewardedVideo;

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ...
        MobileAds.initialize(this, APP_ID);

        rewardedVideo = MobileAds.getRewardedVideoAdInstance(this);
        rewardedVideo.setRewardedVideoAdListener(videosListener());
        loadRewardedvideo();
    }

public void loadRewardedvideo() {
        if (!rewardedVideo.isLoaded()) {
            rewardedVideo.loadAd(AD_ID, new AdRequest.Builder().build());
        }
    }

private RewardedVideoAdListener videosListener() {
        return new RewardedVideoAdListener() {
            @Override
            public void onRewardedVideoAdLoaded() {
                alert("Video Pronto");
                btnVideo.setEnabled(true);
            }

            @Override
            public void onRewardedVideoAdOpened() {

            }

            @Override
            public void onRewardedVideoStarted() {

            }

            @Override
            public void onRewardedVideoAdClosed() {
                alert("Video Assistido!");
                loadRewardedvideo();
            }

            @Override
            public void onRewarded(RewardItem rewardItem) {
                alert("Premio");
            }

            @Override
            public void onRewardedVideoAdLeftApplication() {

            }

            @Override
            public void onRewardedVideoAdFailedToLoad(int i) {
                alert("Falha ao carregar.");
            }
        };
    }
```

According to the @RedBrogdon in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42700666/5561657) now I do not need of a mediator in order to show this rewards videos, what is cool to who is just begining like me, I followed all the steps, of exemple code, and also created on my admob page a project of where I get the APP_ID and AD_ID, however my project do not works! It always return the error code 3 (ERROR_CODE_NO_FILL) when the onRewardedVideoAdFailedToLoad() of listener is called.

Someone knows what is happen?

**Note** - I'm using a real device

**EDIT**

I was reading some articles that said that this error code 3 it's when there is not any error on code, however do not exist any ad to be shown, It's like no ad wanted to be shown in the app, right?

My app has not been published yet, so ok. But can this happen in a published app?

Answer (score 0):

There was the error.
   First you need to load the Ad then check if Ad has been loaded if its loaded show the Ad.You dont require AdMob mediation to show reward Ads if you want Ads to be loaded from different sources where you can choose what type of Ads you can so show so you can use Mediation in such cases.you will need to have accounts in different ad networks to show their ads through Admob.

```
public void loadRewardedvideo() {
rewardedVideo.loadAd(AD_ID, new AdRequest.Builder().build());
    if (rewardedVideo.isLoaded()) {
       rewardedVideo.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: I call the rewardedVideo.show() when the button is enabled (in its onClick()), I was reading some articles that said that this error code 3 it's when there is not any error on code, however do not exist any ad to be shown, It's like no ad wanted to be shown in the app, right? My app has not been published yet, so ok. But can this happen in a published app?